Handling Button Presses in a TabView with a VStack
I have vstack it has tap gesture to print "view". Inside vstack two components are there one is back button and tabView, and inside tabView next button is there. on pressing on back button it is printing "back" but on pressing on next button it is printing next and view.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            
            Button("Back") {
                print("back")
            }
            TabView {
                VStack {
                    Text("View1")
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                          print("View1")
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("View2")
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                          print("View2")
                }
            }
            .background(Color.green)
            Button("Next") {
               print("next")
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Hello")
        }
    }
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

On pressing on next button, it should print next alone

A TabView should always be the outermost view.

well i don't want to be outermost view in my application.is there any fix?

Your code seems wrong, as @koen said, TabView was designed to be on top of the view hierarchy. It should be something like, without VStack.
          TabView
        /    |    \
      Item  Item  Item

In your example above, you were actually tapping on 2 events, button action and tap gesture, because TabView forwarded/received tap action itself, then Button. They overlap each other. That's why it's printing twice. You might want to long press to highlight the button, you can see it will ignore tapGesture.
TabView {
    Button("Next") {
        print("next")
    }
}
.onTapGesture {
    print("Hi")
}
//=> print both `next` and `Hi`


Conclusion: This is a bad design, and you should avoid it to prevent unexpected behavior like above. If you want to customize the app appearance, replace the TabView with your CustomView.
#Update:
I believe it should be a kind of page controller in this scenario. You might want to try the below approach:

PageViewController manages a list of View.

struct PageViewController<Page: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var pages: [Page]
    @Binding var currentPage: Int

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: .scroll,
            navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(
            [context.coordinator.controllers[currentPage]],
            direction: .forward,
            animated: true)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: PageViewController
        var controllers: [UIViewController] = []

        init(_ parent: PageViewController) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.controllers = parent.pages.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                                viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index == 0 {
                return controllers.last
            }
            return controllers[index - 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                                viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index + 1 == controllers.count {
                return controllers.first
            }
            return controllers[index + 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                                didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
                                previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
                                transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            guard completed else { return }
            guard let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first else { return }
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: visibleViewController) else { return }
            parent.currentPage = index
        }
    }
}


A wrapper for the pager.

struct PageView<Page: View>: View {
    var pages: [Page]
    @State private var currentPage = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            PageViewController(pages: pages, currentPage: $currentPage)
        }
    }
}


Now you're good to go, replace the TabView with PageView.

var body: some View {
    ...
    PageView(pages: [
        VStack {
            Text("View1")
        },

        VStack {
            Text("View2")
        }
    ])
    ...
}


is there anywhere to overcome it?

What is your purpose when putting TabView inside a VStack? Why wouldn't you simply put a View instead?

The footer and header templates for the views inside my tabView is same.If i use TabView as TopMost view, then i have to place Header and template inside the views, which makes code redundent.

Could you update the OP to provide more detail about the TabView? I can't guess what it is in this context.

updated in the code

I want to avoid UIKit. is there any workaround?

Well, then I don't think there is an equivalent solution to this. Customizing it like a PageController will need a significant amount of effort. Perhaps TabView with an overriding tapGesture might suffice. It will ignore tapGesture on VStack outside.
